# Echo all category names, apart from one

Tags: theme-development, loop, themes

I've got this simple code, that creates breadcrumbs:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        echo 'home';
        echo " / ";
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            the_category(' / ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " / " . '<a href="#">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo " / " . '<a href="#">' . get_the_title()  . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

And this echoes out:

```
<p class="bread-crumbs">
    <a href="http://fashion-detail.dev">home / </a>
    <a href="http://fashion-detail.dev/?cat=4" title="View all posts in Fashion" rel="category">Fashion</a> / 
    <a href="http://fashion-detail.dev/?cat=16" title="View all posts in Top" rel="category">Top</a> / 
    <a href="#">This is in the fashion category.</a>        
</p>
```

However, it do not want it to show the `a href` tag that links to the `top` category. Is there a way to include a str_replace, or just prevent the_category from calling `top` (I still need the post, I just don't want to link to `top` in the breadcrumbs)?

Answer (score 0):

[`the_category` `echo`s content](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L250). You will not be able to use string manipulation. No strings are `return`ed that you could manipulate. They are just `echo`ed immediately.

You could completely filter out a particular category, which seems to be an option, with this:

```
function cat_filter_wpse_137596($categories) {
  foreach ($categories as $k => $c) {
    if ('uncategorized' === $c->slug) {
      unset($categories[$k]);
    }
  }
  return $categories;
}
```

You'd use it like:

```
    add_filter('get_the_categories','cat_filter_wpse_137596');
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        the_category(' / ');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo " / " . '<a href="#">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo " / " . '<a href="#">' . get_the_title()  . '</a>';
    }
    remove_filter('get_the_categories','cat_filter_wpse_137596');
```

There is no easy way to keep the category and remove the link. You'd need some nasty regex on the [`the_category` filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L212).